# Repulsive force between many rigid cubes

Tags: python, scripting, physics

In order to create repulsive force between the cubes in the figure below, I took the method of "Create a Force force field at the origin of cube and parent it to cube". Simple Python code was written to implement batch processing. When the number of cubes is 16, the calculation result will be obtained very quickly. When the number of squares is 100, it takes 7-8 hours. Do you know how to optimize? Or do you know other ways to quickly set the repulsive force between many rigid cubes?
[image]

Python code：

import bpy

for index in range(0,100):

```
bpy.ops.object.effector_add(type='FORCE', view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=bpy.data.objects['Cube.'+str(index).zfill(3)].location, \
                            layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))  
bpy.context.object.field.strength=100
bpy.context.object.name ='Cube.'+str(index).zfill(3)+'Field'
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.data.objects['Cube.'+str(index).zfill(3)+'Field'].select=True
bpy.data.objects['Cube.'+str(index).zfill(3)].select=True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active=bpy.data.objects['Cube.'+str(index).zfill(3)]
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='OBJECT', keep_transform=False)
```

Comment: Model and Python Code:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s0K6sEPZkGTHUNXxaEnDdVyjyt20ro9f/view

Comment: First thing to optimize bpy code would probably be to avoid operator access (`bpy.ops`) and use alternative low-level access instead (i.e. `bpy.data` in most cases).

Comment: Thanks for your comments@Benedikt ,I will try it.